# Pipreqs generate incorrect requiremnets for Hydra

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt, fb-hydra

I'm using [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) for generating `requirements.txt`. I started using hydra package (see https://hydra.cc/ or [hydra-core](https://pypi.org/project/hydra-core/) package on PyPI). So I would like `pipreqs` to add `hydra-core` dependency automatically when I run.

But, when I checked output of `pipreqs` (directly in `requirements.txt` when running `pipreqs --force` or from console output with `pipreqs --print`) there is **`Hydra==2.5`**. But it's incorrect package (leading to [Hydra](https://pypi.org/project/Hydra/) which is package with a high performance bloom filter). I would expect to see **`hydra-core==1.0.6`** which is the right version of my hydra (`hydra-core` to be correct) package.

Is there anything what should I do differently? Or is there any issue with `pipreqs`?

---

- Python 3.8.6
- pipreqs version: 0.4.10

Comment: This is a common issue, actually (you can see all of the mixups in their "issues" for pipreqs). Most people seem to manually fix the issue. The solution, even from pipreqs' standpoint is not a simple one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the [Hydra package](https://pypi.org/project/Hydra/), first released at 2010 - predated the [Hydra Framework](https://hydra.cc), so I was not able to use name `hydra` as the pypi package name (hence `hydra-core`).
I even reached out to the owner of that project, politely asking if he can let go of that name. I was not surprised when he declined :).

Installing `hydra` instead of `hydra-core` is pretty common mistake for people getting started with [Hydra](https://hydra.cc).

Looking at that project, they do have a [mechanism](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/blob/master/pipreqs/mapping) to help indicate what package to use when seeing an import, which might be helpful. See [this](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/pull/234) PR for example. You may want to open a pull request to add hydra-core to their mapping.
Given that hydra-core is [much more popular](https://pepy.tech/project/hydra-core?versions=*) than the [other hydra](https://pepy.tech/project/hydra?versions=*), I think they will be okay with it.

Comment: Thanks, it seems you are right. First, I created issue there (https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/244). If the solution with updating mapping in pipreqs will be enough I will create PR later.

Comment: @Nerxis: 
1. If this answers your question, please accept. 
2. Please follow-up on the issue you opened. :)

Comment: Yes, I will follow-up but for some reason I didn't receive any notification, thanks for remainder. Regarding answer, I will accept it when PR is merged and everything is working, don't be afraid :-)

Comment: @Nerxis If this solved your issue I would suggest accepting this answer. You should be able to update the mapping file yourself with the guidance provided in this answer.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/pull/247 was merged, it will probably take some time to the next release but you can build directly from master atm. Thanks for your help.

Comment: pipreqs got mysql-connector-python wrong too. I guess it is may due to similar reason.