# doc_controls has not attribute 'inheritable headers'

Tags: tensorflow, pip, airflow

I'm starting this thread with an answer, not a question. The questions are stated at the end:

I tried to add pip package 'tfx' to Apache Airflow using my own Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml. I added my own DAG to Airflow and that failed to load with this error message:

```
    doc_controls has not attribute 'inheritable_header'
```

It cost me only a day to find the cause. When you add this to your Dockerfile..

```
pip install tfx
```

..pip will install txf, tensorflow-2.6.0 and tensorflow-estimator-**2.7.0**. The latter is apparently depending on the not-yet-released code in the github repo tensorflow/docs which contains doc_controls.

So instead add this to keep tensorflow-estimator in line with packages that pip can find:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user \
     tfx==1.3.1 \
     tensorflow==2.6.0 \
     tensorflow-estimator==2.6.0
```

I'm loosing a lot of time solving problems with dependencies between pip packages and pip packages and the underlying C/C++ libraries. Am I the only one?

Here are my questions:

- Am I correct to assume that pip is supposed to figure out which versions of dependencies of tfx to install. Should I normally be able to rely on pip to do this correctly or will pip simply install the latest version of all dependencies without regard to their mutual compatibility?
- On the internet there are many Dockerfile around that do not specify any version numbers of the apt/pip packages to install. Such a Dockerfile is like a box of chocolates right? If you build the dockerfile a time t1 and at time t2 then their contents can differ in terms of versions right?
- In general: Given a docker image why can one not get the Dockerfile that was used to construct the docker image?

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I also keep running into these dependency issues recently. I came across another post which might be of interest: [Resolving new pip backtracking runtime issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65122957/resolving-new-pip-backtracking-runtime-issue). Based off this I think pip does try to figure out what versions of packages to install to avoid conflicts but I guess it sometimes struggles. I tried one of the tools, `pipreqs` but I didn't find it useful for my particular problem. In fact it broke things even more.

Also thanks for the solution to this one, I had the same problem.